# Having a problem with installation of a package that has the architecture of (any) on Ubuntu and also on Raspbian

Tags: apt, software-installation

The output is:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_any.deb 
(--unpack):
package architecture (any) does not match system (amd64)
Selecting previously unselected package libhwloc-plugins:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libhwloc-plugins_2.4.1+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhwloc-plugins:amd64 (2.4.1+dfsg-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_any.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What is your CPU architecture? Raspbian is off-topic here.

Comment: It appears to be a script with no compiling necessary. Is there a reason you don't just clone the version from github?

Comment: You mention raspbian (which is for ARM processors) but paste an AMD64 paste. Are you sure your architecture & release details all match?  You've not said what release; but a *hirsute* or *impish* package is mentioned; it's best if you provide release details as your question implies user understanding errors to me.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Architecture) you can use the special words `all` for an architecture-independent package, and `any` for an architecture-dependent package that can be built for any number of different architectures. You need a package that can be installed in your amd64 architecture OS, so make a backup copy of apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_any.deb, rename the backup to apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_all.deb, change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_all.deb, and try to install it on your amd64 system with the following commands.

```
sudo apt  update
sudo apt install aircrack-ng ethtool hwloc ieee-data
sudo apt install ./apt-dpkg-install-v4lZRv/5-hashcatch_1.2_all.deb
```

To test these commands I downloaded [hashcatch_1.2_any.deb](https://github.com/staz0t/hashcatch/releases/download/1.2/hashcatch_1.2_any.deb) from GitHub, and installed it with the following steps. I didn't need to rename hashcatch_1.2_any.deb in order to install it, but I also tried renaming hashcatch_1.2_any.deb to hashcatch_1.2_all.deb and I was able to install hashcatch_1.2_all.deb successfully too.

1. Download [hashcatch_1.2_any.deb](https://github.com/staz0t/hashcatch/releases/download/1.2/hashcatch_1.2_any.deb) from GitHub.
2. Change directories using `cd` to the directory that contains hashcatch_1.2_any.deb.
3. Run the following commands to install it.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   apt install --simulate ./hashcatch_1.2_any.deb # test for unmet dependencies
   sudo apt install aircrack-ng ethtool hwloc ieee-data # Maybe you can skip this step on your system if you didn't get any unmet dependencies in the previous step.
   sudo apt install ./hashcatch_1.2_any.deb
   ```

Note that the `--simulate` command runs without `sudo` and just provides terminal output about the simulated installation without actually installing anything. The reason for running the `--simulate` command is that I was unable to locate the exact file that you tried to install. Please comment and provide a link to it.